# How to include a html file which contains mathjax equation in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>MathJax POC</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="TestController">

    <!--here, we trying to add a html file which conatins MathJax equation-->
    <div ng-include="'./Notes.html'"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">

        MathJax.Hub.Config({
            tex2jax: {
                inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
                processEscapes: true
            }
        });

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML&delayStartupUntil=onload"></script>   

    <script>

    var testApp = angular.module('testApp',[]);

    testApp.controller('TestController',function($scope, $sce, $timeout){
    });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But When i run this, got an error i.e 
Error: [$parse:lexerr] : http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%202-2%20%5B%5E%5D&p2=m%7D%5E%7B2

I think it is happening because Notes.html file contains MathJax equation. Following are the equation :

**[{{m}^{2}}]**

Also searched a solution for that but i didn't get any solution, so please someone help me out.

**-----Notes.html-----**

The floor of a building consists of 3000 tiles which are rhombus shaped and each of its diagonals are 45 cm and 30 cm in length. Find the total cost of polishing the floor, if the cost per \[{{m}^{2}}\] is Rs 4.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your math equation in controller.

```
<script>
   var testApp = angular.module('testApp',[]);

   testApp.controller('TestController',function($scope, $sce, $timeout){

      $scope.mathEq = "\[{{m}^{2}}\]"
   });
</script>
```

**Notes.html**

The floor of a building consists of 3000 tiles which are rhombus shaped and each of its diagonals are 45 cm and 30 cm in length. Find the total cost of polishing the floor, if the cost per **{{mathEq}}** is Rs 4.

If Notes.html is from remote server, you can escape the characters itself. Refer http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

Comment: But Digit, i think it is not a permanent solution because we load Notest.html file from cloud server, then how we can handle it in controller.

Comment: Oh, do you mean Notes.html is from remote server. I thought it in an application itself.

Comment: I found the solution for you.. You can escape the characters. please read through link here .. [link](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php)